# Styled Html Radio Button Not Checking

Tags: html, css

When I click the radio button, the button is not being clicked and other buttons click status not changing.

CSS is here:

```
  input[type="radio"] 
    {
    display:none;
    }
input[type="radio"] + label
{
    height: 20px;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before {
    content: url("../../../Content/images/Icons/radiounchecked.png");
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 3px;

}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    content: url("../../../Content/images/Icons/radiochecked.png");

}
```

It is MVC 4 project and radio creating here

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.Variations(j).SelectedVariationID, Model.Variations(j).Options(i).OptionID )
```

Generated HTML codes Here :

```
<input checked="true" id="Variations_0__SelectedVariationID" name="Variations[0].SelectedVariationID" type="radio" value="77">
<label for="77">Siyah Çikolata   $0.00</label>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could we have the html code too? ;oP

Comment: Do you try jquery ? addClass your clicked radio input.

Comment: `for="77"` should be `for="Variations_0__SelectedVariationID"`

Comment: Added generated HTML code.

No jquery for radio style

Comment: Of course ! I missed this thank you for answer.

Answer (score -1):

There's not really enough information to figure out what your issue is, but one thing that I do know is that when styling radio/checkboxes, you shouldn't use `:before` for the box, because the click action doesn't activate on it. Try adding a span into your label, and style the span to be the radio/checkbox.

At least, that's how it used to be. Not sure about recently.

Comment: Thank you for answer Nick Dugger but problem was at radio id. I forgot define id to radio button . King King said this and fixed.

Comment: @NickDugger Doing label::before will still work because the :before element goes inside the label element. A click event on the :before will bubble up to the label, which (hopefully) is attached to the input with a "for" attribute.

Comment: I was just speaking from previous experience. It didn't used to work as it should.